# Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected error

Tags: c#

I am having the same problem repeatedly, with no success. I keep getting this error:

*Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected*

I have it twice on two curly braces at the end of my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Asrai
{
    class Program
    {
        public int health = 100;
        public int damage = 0;
        public static int hit = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (hit == 1)
            {
                int operator -(int health,int damage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is probably something simple that I overlooked, but I can't see anything wrong with this code

Comment: What is int operator -(int health,int damage);? Comment that line and see if it compiles successfully.

Comment: it's the code I am using to take the damage from the health, taken from the interne., I already have, it makes little difference

Comment: you can't event access "health" because it's an instance variable which you are trying to access from a static method

Comment: did you mean to write health -= damage? where health and damage are static members?

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile. Are you programming in notepad :P ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
class Program
{
    public static int health = 100;
    public static int damage = 0;
    public static int hit = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (hit == 1)
        {
            health = health - damage; // health -= damage;
        }
    }
}
```

Both ***health*** and ***damage*** need to be ***static*** in order for them to be accessible from a ***static*** context (in this case the ***Main*** method)

```
public static int health = 100;
public static int damage = 0;
```

PS: You should have noticed that your code is wrong simple from the highlighting that this website does to this line of code

```
int operator -(int health,int damage);
```

***int*** is a type. what business would it have in that line of code ?

Comment: It worked, thanks a million. I'd been trying to fix it for ages

Comment: Glad I could help. But, what IDE are you using? Not visual studio I assume. Because it would have given you the errors at compile time.